# How to properly project a Graphics object consisting of line primitives

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, replacement

My problem starts from attempts at depicting overlapping lines of different thickness, i.e.

```
ClearAll[line1, line2, overlapping1, overlapping2, ov1Flat, ov2Flat]
line1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 1}}]}];
line2 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.03], Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 1}}]}];
overlapping1 = Show[{line2, line1}];
```

[image: overlapping lines 2d]

I am often annotating parts of a plot with lines of varying thickness and my preferred method of projecting 2D plots onto 3D is by, well, projecting:

```
ov1Flat = Show[{ContourPlot[Sin[y x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}], overlapping1}];
Graphics3D@(N@First@ov1Flat /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 2.})
```

[image]

This works really well for projecting `Graphics` objects comprised of polygons onto a plane but I am not happy with the behaviour of `Line` as a 3D object: lines of various thicknesses get turned into ugly cylinders and their overlap doesn't show too well. I know I can use `Texture` to do the same thing but I would like to avoid it. I'd need to adjust the position of a rasterized image which I'd need to rasterize to an acceptable quality etc - in short, I find it dirtier.

So I am looking for a failsafe rule that maps lines onto polygons that I can apply to a `Graphics` object before projecting it and turning it into a truly flat `Graphics3D` object.

In trying making a rule for lines consisting of two points, I got the following:

```
overlapping2 = 
  overlapping1 /. {pre1___, Thickness[a_], mid___, Line[c_], 
     post___} :> {pre1, mid, 
     Polygon[
      Transpose@(Transpose@c + 
          4 a (RotationMatrix[π/2].Normalize[
              Flatten@Differences@c]))~Join~
       Transpose@(Transpose@Reverse@c - 
          4 a (RotationMatrix[π/2].Normalize[
              Flatten@Differences@c]))]
     , post};
Show[overlapping2]
```

which probably has a million ways to break, is inefficient etc, but at least works for the toy example of a line consisting of a start and end point.

[image: overlap2]

This replicates the line quite well and once projected is still "flat" with the overlaps showing much better:

```
Show[Graphics3D@(N@
     First@Graphics@overlapping2 /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 
      2.}), Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: line3D]

but it doesn't like getting combined with other objects:

```
ov2Flat=Show[{ContourPlot[Sin[y x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}], overlapping2}];
Graphics3D@(N@First@ov2Flat /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 2.})
```

[image: projected line].

So my question in its most general form would be:

**Is there a transformation rule that one can apply to a `Graphics` object so that the said object can be projected to a truly flat `Graphics3D` object (and look good)?**

I know that for `Text` this would probably be impossible so something that has the right behaviour for `Line` and `Point` primitives would be great. And a "no" answer that would mean I have to use `Texture` is also OK but as I said, I want this to be a last resort.

**----EDIT----**

The reason I want to do the projection is so that I combine two and three dimensional plots. I am stuck with the toy example I made up (which isn't very well suited for this) but it should give an idea:

```
Show[{Plot3D[8 + Sin[y x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {(0.25 #1 - #2) &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, PlotPoints -> 80],
  Graphics3D@(N@
      First@ov2Flat /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 2.})}, 
 PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 6}]
```

[image: projection3]

**----EDIT 2----**

Ok, so the only way out seems to be offsetting each polygonised `Line` a little with respect to the overlapping line and all these lines with respect to the projected plane. I think @belisarius's rule based on the line colour is the simplest one to do that (especially if there's a lot of lines to go through) so I'm going with that.

Comment: Does offsetting the z-value slightly do any good?

Comment: yeah, kind of does. But that means I'd have to project separately all "polygonised" lines from the rest of the graphics objects. I was kind of hoping for something more general.

Comment: Sometimes adding `Opacity[.99]` or similar does also help, but the rendering of coincident polygons is problematic (see also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15735/unintended-edge-extensions-in-3d-cube-rendering)

Comment: `Opacity[.99]` doesn't really help but that is a very helpful link.

Comment: The problem with this question is that it needs a little more motivation. If you are always drawing on a flat (level?) plane why not use a 2D plot? An offset from the plane is probably the best 3D solution and I don't understand the reason you're not satisfied with that. Do you have multiple planes with normals in different directions?

Comment: If you want to do a lot of 3D manipulations with the contour plot and the line, I would definitely suggest combining them together into a single texture on a 3D polygon first. The graphics will become much more responsive.

Comment: Interestingly you can overcome the z-fighting by changing the rendering engine: `Style[Graphics3D[N@First@ov2Flat/.{x_?AtomQ,y_?AtomQ}:>{x,y,2.}],RenderingOptions->{"Graphics3DRenderingEngine"->"BSPTree"}]` but this only seems to work for the on-screen display, not when the graphic is exported.

Comment: v9 sounds like more fun than v8 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a quick fix:

```
s = Graphics3D@(N@First@ContourPlot[Sin[y x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}] /. 
                                          {x_? AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 3});
new = Graphics3D[(N@First@overlapping2 /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 3.1}), 
                                       PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {2, 4}}];

Show[{new, s, new}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

If you chose your line colors (or any other line directive) to be unique, you may do the same without projecting separately:

```
Graphics3D@(N@
     First@ov2Flat /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 2.}) /. 
     {RGBColor[1., 0., 0.], Polygon[l_ ]} :> 
                      {RGBColor[1., 0., 0.], Polygon[Plus[#, {0, 0, .1}] & /@ l]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks a lot (+1) - I know this works but I was kind of hoping I wouldn't have to separately project lines and polygons.

Comment: @gpap See edit please

Comment: this could work actually. The way it is, it would still run into the problem of the overlapping polygonised lines looking bad (if you try to overlap lines of comparable thickness you'll see what I mean). But it's fine as you can make a new rule based on whatever colour the top line has.

Comment: @gpap Of course! The whole stupid idea is based on being able to pick each line by its color and manipulate the "projecting height"

Answer (score 6):

### Projection approach

One way to get the lines to show up nicely is to wrap them in `Tube` and *then* project these tubes down onto the plane. To do projections in a more general setting, I had written a function `project` as an [answer to "How to make a drop-shadow for Graphics3D objects"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-make-a-drop-shadow-for-graphics3d-objects/1030#1030), which however needed some fixes for this answer.

So although the function `project` is overkill for this problem, I'll list it here and show how it can be applied:

```
Options[project] = {"ObjectCenter" -> {0, 0, 0}, "DarkShadow" -> True};

project[x_, direction_, normal_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {d, n, darkShadow, center},
  darkShadow = OptionValue["DarkShadow"];
  center = OptionValue["ObjectCenter"];
  d = Normalize[direction];
  n = Normalize[normal];
  x /. Graphics3D[gr_, opts___] :> Graphics3D[
     {
      If[darkShadow, Black],
      GeometricTransformation[
       If[darkShadow,
        gr /. {
          Glow[_] -> Glow[],

          r_?(MemberQ[{RGBColor, Hue, CMYKColor, GrayLevel}, 
               Head[#]] &) -> Black
          },
        gr
        ],
       Composition[
        TranslationTransform[direction + center],
        Quiet[Check[RotationTransform[{d, n}], Identity],
         {RotationMatrix::degen, RotationTransform::spln}
         ],
        ScalingTransform[10^-3, d],
        Quiet@Check[
          ScalingTransform[1./(n.d), n - (n.d) d],
          Identity
          ],
        TranslationTransform[-center]
        ]
       ]
      },
     opts
     ]
  ]
```

Here are your definitions of the lines, and my way of translating them to 3D:

```
line1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 1}}]}];
line2 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.03], Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 1}}]}];

line1new = 
  Graphics3D[N[First@line1] /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 2.}] /. 
   Line[x__] -> {CapForm["Butt"], Tube[Line[x], .02]};

line2new = 
  Graphics3D[N[First@line2] /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 1.}] /. 
   Line[x__] -> {CapForm["Butt"], Tube[Line[x], .1]};

overlapping1 = Show[{line2new, line1new}]
```

[image: show 3D tubes]

So the lines first of all are *offset vertically*. This is done so that the next step, the *projection*, will layer the thin blue line on top of the red one (which is closer to the bottom plane).

Now I create the planar plot as you did - but separately. Then I combine it with the projection result:

```
cpl3d = Graphics3D[N@First@cpl /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, 0}];

Show[
 project[
  overlapping1, {0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1},
  "DarkShadow" -> False, "ObjectCenter" -> {0, 0, 1}],
 cpl3d
 ]
```

[image: projection]

The result seems to have no visual problems.

To explain how `project` works: the first argument is the `Graphics3D` (in this case `overlapping1` corresponding to the two tubular lines). The second argument is the `direction` in which I want the shadow of this object to be projected. The third argument `normal` is the surface normal of the surface *onto which* we imagine projecting the object. The amount by which the object is translated is given by the length of the vector `direction`.

The projection involves a "flattening step" in which the center of mass of the object is moved into a plane including the origin, and in that step we lose the information where the object was originally. The translation by `direction` is applied starting from the origin.

That's fine if the center of the object was originally near the origin anyway, but in our `overlapping1` object the center is somewhere higher up. I actually want the lowest of the lines to end up on the plane at `z = 0`, but the red line as at `z = 1`. To make this come out right, I have to provide the information that the original position of the object should be taken as `z = 1`, so that after the "flattening step" this original position is first restored before applying the translation in the projection direction `{0, 0, -1}`.

The original position is provided as an option `"ObjectCenter"`. Another option is `"DarkShadow"` which by default is `True`, making shadows appear black or gray. In our case we want colored shadows, so I set this option to `False`.

I'll also have to update this code in the earlier answer linked above, because there I didn't catch an error that appears when projecting straight along the surface normal (since for such cases the function `project` is actually overkill, as I mentioned)... However, with this function you can then also project lines (or rather `Tube`s) onto arbitrary **oblique** surfaces, if desired.

### Edit 2: Texture approach

The ultimate goal seems to involve further 3D manipulations, which may lead to unacceptably large files and sluggish response due to high polygon count (not just with my method above - it depends mainly on the number of polygons in the `ContourPlot`, which is usually rather large).

So I would suggest instead to go with the alternative approach that was already alluded to in the question: make the 2D graphics into a textured polygon. As it happens, [I also had previously written a function for that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4842/245).

It's called `label3D` and takes a any arbitrary input as its first argument, converts it into an `Image` and then puts it as a texture onto a rectangular `Polygon` whose dimensions are given by the arguments `pos`, `xVec`, `tiltAngle` in the code below. Here, `pos` is the location of the bottom left corner of the flattened polygon in 3D space. `xVec` is a vector pointing in the direction along which the baseline of the image should be oriented. The length of this vector is taken as the width of the polygon in 3D space. `tiltAngle` is the angle (in radians) by which the label is rotated around its baseline.

```
label3D[s_, pos_, xVec_, tiltAngle_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{ra, width, height, r}, 
   ra = Rasterize[
     Style[HoldForm[s], FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Style]], 
      Magnification -> 10], 
     Evaluate@
      Apply[Sequence, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Rasterize]]], 
     "Image"];
   {width, height} = ImageDimensions[ra];
   r = SetAlphaChannel[ra, 
     With[{color = 
        Apply[List, 
         ColorConvert[
          "TransparentColor" /. {opts} /. {"TransparentColor" -> 
             Apply[RGBColor, ImageData[ra][[2, 2]]]}, "RGB"]]}, 
      Binarize[ra, (Norm[# - color] > .005) &]]];
   Translate[(* //to make lefthand corner pos*)
    Rotate[(*   //around z axis*)
     Rotate[(* //around y axis*)
      Rotate[(* //tilt around x axis*)
       Scale[(*//to make width equal|
        xVec|*){EdgeForm[FrameStyle /. {opts} /. FrameStyle -> None], 
         Texture[ImageData@r],(* //
         Texture fills polygon initially in the xz plane*)
         Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {width, 0, 0}, {width, 0, height}, {0, 0,
             height}}, 
          VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
             1}}]}, Norm[xVec]/width, {0, 0, 0}], 
       tiltAngle, {1, 0, 0}],(* //x rotation*)
      Arg[Chop@N[Norm[xVec[[1 ;; 2]] + I xVec[[3]]]]], {0, -1, 
       0}],(* //y rotation*)
     Arg[Chop@N[xVec[[1]] + I xVec[[2]]]], {0, 0, 1}],(* //z rotation*)
    pos]];
```

The function recognizes the additional options `Magnification` (and also `ImageSize`)  to determine the resolution of the rasterized image.

But in this application I chose to instead specify a fixed `ImageSize` for the original 2D plot, to make sure the line thicknesses are correct relative to the image size.

Here is the application to your problem. The 2D plot is made without tick marks and with no `PlotRangePadding` so that it fits snugly into the polygon of dimension $8\times 8$ in the 3D plot.

Although the rasterization step may take a second or two, the result is a smaller 3D graphics object that can be rotated more smoothly:

```
ClearAll[line1, line2, overlapping1, ov1Flat]
line1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 1}}]}];
line2 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.03], Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 1}}]}];
overlapping1 = Show[{line2, line1}];

ov1Flat = 
  Show[{ContourPlot[Sin[y x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}], overlapping1}, 
   ImageSize -> 360, PlotRangePadding -> 0, FrameTicks -> None];

g = Graphics3D[
   label3D[ov1Flat, {-4, -4, 0}, {8, 0, 0}, -Pi/2]];

Show[
 {
  Plot3D[8 + Sin[y x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {(0.25 #1 - #2) &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, PlotPoints -> 80],
  g
  },
 PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 6}]
```

[image: label3D]

Comment: this looks somewhat more promising (+1) but I have still to understand whether it can be done a little more automatically. Say I have a 2D plot with 20 lines, some overlapping, it seems I still have to go over each line and add the offsets so the projection does the job correctly.

Comment: Ok, I get that. I don't really want to do manipulations in 3D but rather I want to export the 3D plot in decent quality. My workflow so far was to combine whatever projections I needed into one `Graphics3D` object and export the final result (without displaying it) to PDF forcing rasterization at the very end by using a transparent prolog (your method).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my try at it. I apologize for using the Presentations Application (and John Browne's GrassmannAlgebra package also) but it makes it easy for me. First I used GrassmannAlgebra to obtain an expression for the perpendicular lines to a given line with start and end points. (I suppose it's basic geometry but I need a computer!)

```
RectangleLine[start_, end_, width_] :=
 Module[{x0, x1, y0, y1, p1, p2, p3, p4, halfperpendicular},
  {x0, y0} = start;
  {x1, y1} = end;
  halfperpendicular = {(width (y0 - y1))/(
    2 Sqrt[(x0 - x1)^2 + (y0 - y1)^2]), (width (-x0 + x1))/(
    2 Sqrt[(x0 - x1)^2 + (y0 - y1)^2])};
  p1 = start - halfperpendicular;
  p2 = start + halfperpendicular;
  p3 = end + halfperpendicular;
  p4 = end - halfperpendicular;
  Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4}]
  ]
```

Here is an example of a thick and thin line.

```
<< Presentations`

Draw2D[
 {{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red], 
   RectangleLine[{0, 0}, {4, -4}, 0.2]},
  {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Black], 
   RectangleLine[{0, 0}, {4, -4}, 0.03]}},
 Frame -> True,
 ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

The following draws the lines on top of a contour plot. I save the contour primitives and line primitives separately. One of the problems that you may have is contrast between the lines and the contour plot. I used pastel colors for the contour plot so the lines will better stand out.

```
Draw2D[
 {contourDraw =
   ContourDraw[Sin[y x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> 5, 
    ColorFunction -> ColorData["Pastel"]],
  plotLines = {{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red], 
     RectangleLine[-{4, 1}, {4, 1}, 0.4]},
    {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Black], 
     RectangleLine[-{4, 1}, {4, 1}, 0.03]}}},
 Frame -> True,
 ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

Finally, here is the 3D plot. NeutralLighting generates a set of Lighting options often similar to Lighting -> "Neutral", but with much more control. We can control the amount of light that comes from the directional lights and the amount that comes from ambient light. For the curved surface we want more directional light to give shading to the surface. For the contour plot and lines we want more ambient light. One of the very nice features of Mathematica graphics is that one can intersperse lighting options with graphics primitives and that is what I have done here. Another feature I used here was fewer PlotPoints and increased MaxRecursion. This is generally more efficient. Notice that I did raise the lines above the surface. You just have to do it.

```
Draw3DItems[
 {NeutralLighting[0, 0.6, 0.2],
  Draw3D[8 + Sin[y x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {(0.25 #1 - #2) &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
   PlotStyle -> Orange],
  NeutralLighting[0, 0.3, 0.6],
  contourDraw // RaiseTo3D[0 &],
  plotLines // RaiseTo3D[0.1 &]},
 NiceRotation,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

I don't know enough about your final objective but there are many ways to present information. Often multiple images are clearer than cramming too much into a single image.

Comment: Please add your customary _"which I sell"_ part. Thanks

Comment: @ Belisarius As long as those who are asking questions whose results will be used in their remunerated work, or in their schoolwork are also asked to state this fact. And the fact that these applications are sold is clearly stated on my profile page.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers and products, and I would like you to continue answering and abide by the [site policies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/152358) at the same time.

Comment: @ Belisarius I think it is discriminatory and puts me as a second class citizen. Does every answer state that one must purchase Stephen Wolfram's expensive application? I don't answer many questions but when I do I think the answers are simple and high quality. I don't make peanuts from it. It takes time so perhaps I have better things to do.

Comment: My intention is not to discriminate you in any way, and I fully agree about the quality of your answers. But these sites have been evolving for a few years now and like in any long standing community there are a few behavioral rules and policies already established (and not all of them fit me either). I think you may post a question on [meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions) about what other users think about this issue and then decide what to do with your time. Also, please consider that writing a standard disclaimer, perhaps at the end of your posts isn't _that_ hard.

Comment: thanks for your answer @DavidPark. "Often multiple images are clearer than cramming too much into a single image" I couldn't agree more but the academic publishing business is not too happy about long papers :)

Comment: David, belisarius is just trying to help you abide by site policy so don't get into trouble.  I encourage you to raise this question on http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/ as I believe it is within the purview of the elected moderators (of which I am one) to adjust that policy in this regard, but it should come from a reasoned discussion where all opinions may be voiced.