# Is there something like DensityPlot3D to visualize atomic orbitals?

Tags: plotting, physics, chemistry

I'm visualizing some hydrogen like atomic orbitals.  For looking at plane slices of the probability density, the `DensityPlot` function works well, and with something like:

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[ psi1XYsq[u, v, z], {u, -w, w}, {v, -w, w} ,
  Mesh -> False, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 45,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]
 , {{w, 10}, 1, 20}
 , {z, 1, 20, 1}
 ]
```

I can get a nice plot [image: hybrid orbital sample plot in x y plane]

I was hoping that there was something like a `DensityPlot3D` so that I could visualize these in 3D, but I don't see such a function.  I was wondering how `DensityPlot` be simulated using other plot functions, so that the same idea could be applied to a 3D plot to construct a `DensityPlot3D` like function?

Comment: You may be interested in [heatmap density 3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17260/5478)

Comment: Or [how to visualize 4D function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19575/5478)

Comment: `Image3D` works, apart from interpolation. A question arises, though: how you would be able to interpret the results? In general, isosurfaces are much more practical than images which look like fuzzy, vague clouds at best, opaque mass with hidden internal structure at worst.

Comment: @kirma "fuzzy, vague clouds" - sounds like an orbital ;)

Comment: @Kuba, yes, that 4D visualization answer by halmir looks like what I was looking for.

Comment: There is now [DensityPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot3D.html) in version 10.2. In the Applications section, there is an example of visualizing hydrogen orbitals.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the version 10.2, there is a builtin `DensityPlot3D` function, which can be used to visualize orbitals.

```
a0=1;

ψ[{n_, l_, m_}, {r_, θ_, ϕ_}] :=With[{ρ = 2 r/(n a0)}, 
 Sqrt[(2/(n a0))^3 (n - l - 1)!/(2 n (n + l)!)] Exp[-ρ/2] ρ^
  l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, ρ] SphericalHarmonicY[l, 
   m, θ, ϕ]]

DensityPlot3D[(Abs@ψ[{3, 2, 0}, {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
     ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}])^2, {x, -10 a0, 
  10 a0}, {y, -10 a0, 10 a0}, {z, -15 a0, 15 a0}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Or use `ListDensityPlot3D`:

```
data = Block[
 {nψ = 
   CompileWaveFunction[ψ[3, 1, 0, r, ϑ, φ]], data, vol},
 Table[Abs[nψ[x, y, z]]^2, {z, -20, 20, 0.25}, {y, -20, 20, 0.25}, {x, -20, 20, 0.25}]];

ListDensityPlot3D[data]
```

[image]

The function definition of the wave function is the same as in [the other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47336/1364) in this question.

Comment: I wonder how fast it is. Like `Image3D`?

Comment: @Jens It seems to be slightly slower in giving back the result than Image3D on my computer. I just realized I'm using a library computer which is much powerful than my old laptop, so I compared the two again on the same machine I'm using, `ListDensityPlot3D` seem to slightly slower.

Comment: @RunnyKine Yes. It appeared in the user portal. Our university has a site license, and I received the email notice several days ago, but the new version only appeared today in my user portal.

Comment: @Jens I think the chief advantage of `DensityPlot3D` over `Image3D` is in `OpacityFunction` and `OpacityFunctionScaling`. Combined with `ColorFunction`, it really is a powerful tool for changing what is visible in the function.

Comment: It's a bit slow on my computer, I guess `ListDensityPlot3D` is not well optimized.

Comment: Wonderful.But as I know,the`{2,1，-1}`or`{2,1,1}`will give a wrong answer?It should give [this result](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-11-06-01-27-21.png).

Comment: @yode your py, pz are linear combinations of the eigenstates: $p_{y,z} = 2p_{m=1} \pm i 2p_{m=-1}$ upto a normailzation constant.

Comment: I'm sorry,I don't know how to use your code to draw [$2p_x$](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-11-06-01-27-21.png) or [$3d_{xy}$](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-11-21-06-25-53.png).I just can reproduce the $2p_z$ and $3d_{z^2}$.Can you update for such case?

Answer (score 36):

In an [presentation](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=105/?fp=left&video=1554) by Markus van Almsick, he gives an solution to visualize atomic orbitals using Image3D.

Radius wave function (hydrogen):

```
R[n_Integer?Positive, l_Integer?NonNegative, r_] :=
 Block[{ρ = (2 r)/n}, 
   Sqrt[(2/n)^3 (n - l - 1)!/(2 n (n + l)!)] E^(-ρ/2) ρ^l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, ρ]] /; l < n
```

full wave function:

```
ψ[n_, l_, m_, r_, ϑ_, φ_] := ψ[n, l, m, r, ϑ, φ] = 
  FullSimplify[R[n, l, r] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, ϑ, φ], {r >= 0, ϑ ∈ Reals, φ ∈ Reals}]


CompileWaveFunction = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}},
   Block[{ρ = x^2 + y^2, r, ϑ, φ},
    If[ρ > 0,
     r = Sqrt[ρ + z^2]; ϑ = ArcCos[z/r]; φ = ArcTan[x, y],
     r = Abs[z]; ϑ = π/2 Sign[z]; φ = 0];
     #
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ] &;
```

color function:

```
colorFunction = (Blend[{
      {0., RGBColor[0.7, 0.8, 1., 0.]}, 
      {0.1, RGBColor[0., 0.7, 0.1, 0.012]}, 
      {0.4, RGBColor[1., 0.1, 0.03169, 0.06723]}, 
      {1., RGBColor[1., 0.95051, 0., 0.10963]}}, #] &)
```

plot 3p orbital

```
Block[
 {nψ = 
   CompileWaveFunction[ψ[3, 1, 0, r, ϑ, φ]], data, vol},
 data = Table[Abs[nψ[x, y, z]]^2, {z, -20, 20, 0.25}, {y, -20, 20, 0.25}, {x, -20, 20, 0.25}];
 vol = RawArray["Byte", Round[(255/Max[data]) data]];
 Image3D[vol, "Byte", Background -> Black, 
  Method -> {"FastRendering" -> True, "InterpolateValues" -> True}, 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction, BoxRatios -> 1]
 ]
```

[image]

it's quite smooth to rotate the Image3D object

[image]

---

We can also visualize the atomic orbital by plotting the isosurface:

```
Block[{nψ = CompileWaveFunction[ψ[3, 2, 0, r, ϑ, φ]]},
 ContourPlot3D[Abs[nψ[x, y, z]]^2, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}, 
  PlotPoints -> 15, Contours -> {0.00002}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"]@Rescale[Arg[nψ[x, y, z]], {-π, π}]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None]
 ]
```

[image]

and make a animation showing different isosurfaces

```
plots = ParallelTable[
   Block[{nψ = CompileWaveFunction[ψ[4, 2, 1, r, ϑ, φ]]}, 
     ContourPlot3D[
      Abs[nψ[x, y, z]]^2, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 17, Contours -> {ct}, 
      ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"]@Rescale[Arg[nψ[x, y, z]], {-π, π}]], 
      Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None, 
      ViewPoint -> {0.98, -2.76, 1.7}, ViewVertical -> {-0.004, -0.117, 0.993}]],
   {ct, 0.00003, 0.000015, -0.0000005}
   ];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

[image]

Answer (score 27):

I recently revisited this, and found that `RegionPlot3D` is by far the fastest way to plot orbitals, compared to `Image3D` and `ContourPlot3D`. I was surprised by the difference, so I thought it's worth posting this.

In addition, I also made the process of choosing the plot parameters automatic, based on simple estimates for the size of the orbital wave function. So you don't have to find the right contour value by trial and error. This automation allows me to plot large numbers of orbitals in one go.

Below, I'm plotting the first ten orbitals in a systematic table, and the whole table takes about as long as doing one or two such plots using `ContourPlot3D` (depending on what functions I try). There was also no need to compile any of the functions, making the code quite straightforward.

```
Clear[rMin, rMax, r, θ, ϕ];
{rMin[n_, l_], rMax[n_, l_]} = 
  r /. Simplify[
    Solve[(l (l + 1))/r^2 - 2/r == -(1/n^2), r], 
    n > 0];

sphericalToCartesian = 
  Thread[{r, θ, ϕ} -> {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
     ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]], Arg[x + I y]}];

ψ[n_, l_, m_][r_, θ_, ϕ_] := 
 Sqrt[ (n - l - 1)!/(n + l)!] E^(-(r/n)) ((2 r)/n)^l 2/
  n^2 LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, (2 r)/n] SphericalHarmonicY[l, 
   m, θ, ϕ]

ClearAll[plotOrbital];
plotOrbital[f_, range_, contour_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 RegionPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Abs[f[r, θ, ϕ] /. sphericalToCartesian]^2 > 
    contour], {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, {z, -range, 
   range}, opt, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 35, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotTheme -> "Classic"]

grid = Table[
   Labeled[plotOrbital[ψ[n, l, m], 2 n^2, .05/n^6], 
    Row[{"n = ", n, ", ℓ = ", l, ", m = ", m}]], {n, 1, 
    3}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, l}];

TableForm[grid]
```

[image: orbitals]

Above, the complete hydrogenic orbital wave function is `ψ`. 
Given the principal quantum number `n`, the energy is known. Setting the energy equal to the effective potential yields the classical turning points, `{rMin[n_, ℓ_], rMax[n_, ℓ_]}`. This is used to determine the required plot size automatically: If the linear dimension `r` scales with $n^2$, then the volume scales with $n^6$. For a normalized wave function, we can then estimate that the probability density at a typical point will decrease with $1/n^6$. Therefore, I choose the threshold for the equi-probability contour to scale with this factor. Here is a check to verify what I said about the length scale:

```
Simplify[rMax[n, 0], n > 0]

(* ==> 2 n^2 *)
```

This is the largest achievable radius because I set the angular momentum `l` to zero.

In `sphericalToCartesian`, I write down how to convert to Cartesian coordinates (instead of using built-in functions which differ too much between *Mathematica* versions).

`plotOrbital` does the plotting for a given wave function `f`. In producing the `grid` of orbitals, I choose the parameters as described above.

---

**Edit: volumetric slices**

To show that the `RegionPlot` approach is also able to provide multiple contours, and to show how these layered contours can give us information about the volume in 3D, here I first combine several outputs of `plotOrbital` with different contour values in a single `Show`. The surfaces have been given their own `PlotStyle`. Then I put the resulting 3D graphics in a `Manipulate` that allows you to slice through the layers in real time:

```
With[{n = 3, l = 2, m = 0}, 
 orb = Show[
   Table[plotOrbital[ψ[n, l, m], 2 n^2, c/n^6, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.6`], Hue[c]]], {c, 0.3`, 
     0.05`, -0.04`}], PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic]]

With[{n = 3},
 Manipulate[
  Show[orb, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
   ViewVector -> {{35, -35, 5}, {0, 0, 0}}, ViewAngle -> Pi/4, 
   PlotRange -> {{-#, #}, {y, #}, {-#, #}} &[2 n^2]], {y, -2 n^2, 
   2 n^2}]]
```

[image: slices]

The trick to get slices and hollow spaces between layers in `RegionPlot3D` is to cut off the plot with a reduced `PlotRange`. To still keep the object fixed in the view port (instead of moving around to stay centered with the changing `PlotRange`), I add fixed values for the `ViewVector` and `ViewAngle`. This trick using `PlotRange` doesn't work if you cut the range off directly inside the `RegionPlot3D`. You have to do it after the fact with `Show`.

Again, the drawing of multiple layers is very fast using `RegionPlot3D`. It could even be sped up more using `ParallelTable`.

**Edit2**

In *Mathematica* version 10, the volumetric slices can also be achieved using the [`ClipPlanes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html) option:

```
With[{n = 3}, 
 Manipulate[
  Show[orb, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
   ViewVector -> {{35, -35, 5}, {0, 0, 0}}, ViewAngle -> Pi/4, 
   ClipPlanes -> {{0, 1, 0, 1.2 y}}], {{y, 0}, -n^2, n^2}]]
```

The output is the same as in the previous animation.

Comment: That's fantastic! Indeed `RegionPlot3D` is much faster. And it also solves the problem of holes in `ContourPlot3D`.

Answer (score 24):

My preferred method for this kind of thing is projecting each dimension onto a plane and then combining them together. I think MATLAB has similar functionality. Mind you, the answers and comments on my [question about projecting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30507/how-to-properly-project-a-graphics-object-consisting-of-line-primitives) are right in pointing out that this will become inefficient for high polygon counts (essentially more `PlotPoints`) so if you want to `Manipulate` in a smooth way, you may want to use `Texture`. See [this relevant question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/how-to-show-solid-bodies-using-volumetric-rendering) for details on that.

Now, I haven't got your function `psi1XYsq` so I will pick a double gaussian:

```
E^(-(x^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 3)^2)/10) + E^(-((x + 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z + 2)^2)/25)
```

The idea is to use something similar to the function @Jens is using in his answer to [How to make a drop-shadow for a Graphics3D objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-make-a-drop-shadow-for-graphics3d-objects/1030#1030).

```
Block[{d1, d2, d3, function, options, opacity, x0, y0, z0, min, max},
 {min, max} = {-9, 9};
 {x0, y0, z0} = {0., 0., 0.};
 opacity = 0.9;
 function[x_, y_, z_] := 
  E^(-(x^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 3)^2)/10) + 
   E^(-((x + 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z + 2)^2)/25);
 options = Sequence @@ {PlotPoints -> 45, Mesh -> None, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"};
 d1 = First@DensityPlot[function[x, y, z0], {x, min, max}, {y, min, max}, 
     Evaluate@options] /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, z0};
 d2 = First@DensityPlot[function[x, y0, z], {x, min, max}, {z, min, max}, 
     Evaluate@options] /. {x_?AtomQ, z_?AtomQ} -> {x, y0, z};
 d3 = First@DensityPlot[function[x0, y, z], {y, min, max}, {z, min, max}, 
     Evaluate@options] /. {y_?AtomQ, z_?AtomQ} -> {x0, y, z};
 Show[Graphics3D[{d1, d2, d3}, Lighting -> "Neutral"] /. 
   GraphicsComplex[xx__] -> {Opacity[opacity], GraphicsComplex[xx]}]
 ]
```

[image: 3d image]

The code is straightforward: `min`, `max` define the range for each variable, `{x0, y0, z0}` define the projection planes, and `opacity` the `Opacity`. You will notice I have turned off `ColorFunctionScaling` so that each slice is bright according to an absolute value and they merge together nicely. If your function is not normalised you may want to normalise it before doing that.

If you can afford lowering the `PlotPoints`, `Manipulate` isn't too bad, and you can make animations that look like volumetric rendering (apologies for the 300K gif):

```
Table[Block[{d1, d2, d3, function, options, opacity, x0, y0, z0, min, 
    max},
   {min, max} = {-9, 9};
   {x0, y0, z0} = {0., t, 0.};
   opacity = 0.9;
   function[x_, y_, z_] := 
    E^(-(x^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 3)^2)/10) + 
     E^(-((x + 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z + 2)^2)/45);
   options = 
    Sequence @@ {PlotPoints -> 25, Mesh -> None, 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
      ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"};
   d1 = First@
      DensityPlot[function[x, y, z0], {x, min, max}, {y, min, max}, 
       Evaluate@options] /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, z0};
   d2 = First@
      DensityPlot[function[x, y0, z], {x, min, max}, {z, min, max}, 
       Evaluate@options] /. {x_?AtomQ, z_?AtomQ} -> {x, y0, z};
   d3 = First@
      DensityPlot[function[x0, y, z], {y, min, max}, {z, min, max}, 
       Evaluate@options] /. {y_?AtomQ, z_?AtomQ} -> {x0, y, z};
   Show[Graphics3D[{d1, d2, d3}, Lighting -> "Neutral"] /. 
     GraphicsComplex[xx__] -> {Opacity[opacity], 
       GraphicsComplex[xx]}]
   ], {t, 9, -9, -1.5}];
Export["3d.gif", %];
```

[image: 3dGif]

Comment: What does your {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, z0} replacement in this code do?

Comment: I adds a third dimension to every pair of 2d coordinates of the density plot.

Comment: The new (in 10.4) function [`SliceDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html) automates this.