# Combine 2D images perpendicular to each other

Tags: plotting

I would like to create a slice plot from multiple density plots in *Mathematica*. A solution for this probem has been posted in this forum before ([Is there something like DensityPlot3D to visualize atomic orbitals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32378/is-there-something-like-densityplot3d)). But how would I go about the problem if I only have Images and no functions.

The result should look like this:

[image: this]

Comment: [Thanks to @gpap](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32441/5478)

Comment: I think the old title was better, this post will stay here so if one will look for that matlab functionality this would pop up. Also, you do not have to sign, just edit your profile and we will see this in miniature. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Take a look at the documentation page of `Texture` and look under Applications -> Volume rendering.  Does the example shown there help?  It starts with images and gives the kind of plot you are looking for.