# MATLAB to Mathematica: coneplot

Tags: plotting, visualization, matlab

Does *Mathematica* have a function, similar to the one called `coneplot` in MATLAB? Given some spatial coordinates $x, y, z$ and velocity components $v_x,v_y,v_z$, it is able to produce the following graphs:

[image: coneplot]

When I plot my data with `ListVectorPlot3D`, I don't get any arrows shown. Here is a sample data, in the form $((x,y,z),(v_x,v_y,v_z))$:

```
data={{{0., 0.847912, 9.48902}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0.00773322, -0.0110065, 
   9.09927}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{-1.00008, -0.0623481, 9.49984}, {0., 0.,
    0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 10.8969}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 
   12.5007}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 14.1046}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 15.5729}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 
   16.6107}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 17.3334}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 18.0983}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 
   18.8639}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 19.9409}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 21.3189}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 
   22.822}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 24.6036}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 26.2343}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.08457, -0.0217237, 10.6779}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.11085, -0.0731095, 12.19}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.1131, -0.0651947, 13.7893}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.10496, -0.0720509, 15.108}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.12255, -0.0365039, 16.0888}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.12699, -0.00227834, 16.8818}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{-1.15057,
    0.0126093, 17.6497}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{-1.13931, -0.015588, 
   18.4211}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{-1.03192, -0.0742988, 19.1016}, {0., 0.,
    0.}}, {{-1.24186, -0.0317904, 19.9972}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.14942, -0.0360112, 20.9677}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.09896, -0.0167395, 21.9511}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.117, -0.0452791, 23.2337}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.1522, -0.056303, 24.8936}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.09607, -0.110654, 26.195}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{0.103537, -0.0647147, 26.6637}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 
   0.847912, 41.3051}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{-0.012139, -0.0295375, 
   40.9221}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{-0.857944, -0.0671514, 41.3642}, {0., 
   0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 42.4678}, {0., 4.67035*10^-7, 0.}}, {{0.,
    0.847912, 43.5378}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{-0.979967, -0.033538, 
   42.2371}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{-1.14769, -0.0351505, 43.0033}, {0., 0.,
    0.}}, {{-0.979351, -0.0342237, 43.8374}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.23767, -0.0499179, 44.5971}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.13972, -0.0000850668, 45.3128}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.12545, -0.00826265, 46.0778}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.1223, -0.0359113, 46.8929}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.12465, -0.055138, 47.8623}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.09846, -0.0144483, 49.0776}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.10899, -0.0625359, 50.4507}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.14579, -0.108309, 52.0417}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.12848, -0.01126, 54.0108}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{-1.11299, -0.0970175, 55.2159}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 
   0.847912, 44.6206}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 45.3961}, {0., 
   0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 46.2075}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 
   47.3219}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 48.6172}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 50.0586}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 
   51.6502}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 53.7857}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{0., 0.847912, 55.2595}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{0.119852, -0.0804816, 55.6719}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{1.38231, -0.0646805, 9.63683}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{3.08676, -0.0356642, 10.2185}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{3.98277, 
   0.0329428, 10.6312}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{1.64587, 0.847912, 
   10.1128}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{2.94532, 0.847912, 10.6054}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{3.0844, 0.847912, 26.2343}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{6.37314, 
   0.847912, 26.2343}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{8.83598, 0.847912, 
   26.2343}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{2.68672, -0.0254293, 26.6613}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{5.13989, -0.0481681, 26.6588}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{7.07074, -0.0263853, 26.6521}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{8.87196, 
   0.0308362, 26.6941}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0.908045, -0.0256653, 
   41.2951}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{0.90812, -0.0305627, 42.1266}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{1.09331, -0.0723344, 42.9721}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{1.03446, -0.06788, 43.5403}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{1.9443, -0.0212229, 43.8278}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{2.52323, 
   0.00655421, 44.1426}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{1.47266, 0.847912, 
   44.0959}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{1.47266, 0.847912, 44.6541}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{3.48462, 0.847912, 55.2595}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{9.45979, 
   0.847912, 55.2595}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{15.9244, 0.847912, 
   55.2595}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{20.8183, 0.847912, 55.2595}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{24.5798, 0.847912, 55.2595}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{27.9807, 
   0.847912, 55.2595}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{4.19646, -0.079758, 
   55.6822}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{9.8436, -0.111618, 55.6824}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{17.6324, -0.0328765, 55.6789}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{23.6589, -0.044735, 55.6773}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{27.8005, -0.0722351, 55.6708}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{2.94532, 
   0.847912, 11.1635}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{2.62106, -0.0129568, 
   44.6594}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{3.34577, -0.0199615, 44.9502}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{3.9942, 0.0362858, 45.2367}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{2.27968, 
   0.847912, 44.96}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{2.94532, 0.847912, 
   45.2124}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{2.94532, 0.847912, 45.7705}, {0., 0., 
   0.}}, {{4.30519, -0.0509312, 11.19}, {0., 0., 0.}}, {{5.04605, 
   0.847912, 11.9598}, {0., 0., 0.}}}
```

Comment: `VectorPlot3D` or `ListVectorPlot3D` with specyfic `VectorStyle` will give you cones. About the box: [something like DensityPlot3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32378/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Please see my edit. I can't make it work with `ListvectorPlot3D` -- but I've added some of my data.

Comment: @Kuba Hope it is fine now, please let me know if it is not. Really appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Why `Last /@ Last /@ data` is all zeros?

Comment: Favorited, just to remind me to see what awesome solution Kuba & co. come up with...

Comment: @mohsen This is just how my simulated data is (it's not random data)

Comment: @BillyJean If they're all zeros then there's nothing to plot!!  Of course it "doesn't work" with ListVectorPlot3D.  All the vectors have zero length, and they're invisible.

Comment: While responding to @Szabolcs's comment, can you also specify what features are most important to you?  Cones as arrows? Pretty specular cones? Cone sizes? pretty axes?  If it is "all of the above", then at least prioritizing might help out a bit.

Comment: @Szabolcs Even if I use `data=data+1`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @bobthechemist If I can choose freely, then magnitude of the velocities is the most imporant -- i.e., is it possible to color them after their magnitude?

Comment: Is `VectorColorFunction->Hue` what you are after?

Comment: @bobthechemist thanks, that is fine!

Answer (score 9):

Just tossing a thought out there.  Using the following sample data from [`ListVectorPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListVectorPlot3D.html), Graphics directives can be applied to `VectorStyle` to get a shape you desire:

```
vectors = 
  Table[{{x, y, z}, {y, x - x^3, z}}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, 0.2}, {y, -2, 2, 
    0.2}, {z, -1, 1, 0.1}];
ListVectorPlot3D[vectors, VectorScale -> 0.05, 
 VectorStyle -> {Specularity[White, 20], Red, 
   Graphics3D[Cone[{{-2, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}}, 0.5]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Vector list plotting requires a structured grid of datapoints, otherwise the interpolation of the points fails and you get an empty plot without warning.  Under circumstances where you cannot obtain data on a structured grid, creating a plot with graphics directives may be a better alternative.

Using your `data = data + 1` option:

```
Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 20], {ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Norm[#[[2]]]], 
  Cone[{#[[1]], #[[1]] + 1 + 1 #[[2]]}, 0.5 Norm[#[[2]]]]} & /@ data}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not a terribly pretty plot IMO, but I don't know what you are expecting from the sample data.

Comment: Thanks -- is there a way to do the same with the same format as my data? I know the velocities are zero, but say you use `data=data+1` instead.

Comment: @BillyJean your data fall on an unstructured grid, and the interpolation function used by `ListVectorPlot3D` is having troubles with that.  If it is possible to generate the data on a structured grid, then you will run in to fewer problems.