# Need help in understanding hydrogen orbitals code

Tags: plotting, physics

I just got a copy of Mathematica and I'm busy learning the basics. I got mathematica so I can plot hydrogen orbitals but I'm completely lost. I looked around and I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88150):

```
a0 = 1;

ψ[{n_, l_, m_}, {r_, θ_, ϕ_}] :=
  With[{ρ = 2 r/(n a0)}, 
    Sqrt[(2/(n a0))^3 (n - l - 1)!/(2 n (n + l)!)] Exp[-ρ/2] ρ^l 
      LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, ρ] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ]]

DensityPlot3D[
  (Abs @ 
    ψ[
      {3, 2, 0}, 
      {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}])^2, 
  {x, -10 a0, 10 a0}, {y, -10 a0, 10 a0}, {z, -15 a0, 15 a0}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Can I get a quick explanation of what's going on here? I understand that the first part is just defining the hydrogen wave function, but what about the second part? What does the `{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}` term do? Also, is the `Abs @` the absolute square of the wave function?

Comment: Please state where you got the code from. If it was on this site, make sure to include a link (not just to give credit to the author, but also to be able to get better explanations). The questions you're asking should be obvious if you look at the documentation for `Abs` and `DensityPlot3D` (the latter uses Cartesian coordinates, whereas the wave function is in spherical coords.)

Comment: Oops, right here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88150/41521

Comment: I'm sure @xslittlegrass will be able to explain the code if necessary. Bu I think what I mentioned above are the main points.

Comment: Yes, but not very obvious to me. I get that they are converting spherical to cartesian. I get how r=sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2] but what does ArcTan[z,sqrt[x^2+y^2]] mean? Is this a conversion to $\theta$? Why is there a comma placed inside?

Comment: Check the documentation for `ArcTan` with two arguments; it gives the arc tan of the ratio taking into account which quadrant it is in.

Comment: Whenever you use code that is not originally yours, please remember to link to where you got it from.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Abs @`*expresion* is the prefix notation for `Abs[`*expresion*`]`
2. The 2nd argument of `ψ` indicates that it wants spherical coordinates.

   ```
   {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}
   ```

   is just transforming a point given in Cartesian coordinates into spherical coordinates.
3. I don't see the need for `Abs @`.

```
DensityPlot3D[
  ψ[{3, 2, 0},
    {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}]^2,
  {x, -10 a0, 10 a0}, {y, -10 a0, 10 a0}, {z, -15 a0, 15 a0},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

gives the same plot as your code.

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you! What is the comma in the ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] and ArcTan[x, y]}]^2 terms supposed to mean? Aren't we just converting $\theta = \arccos{\frac{z}{r}}$ and $\phi=\arctan{\frac{y}{x}}$? Plus, shouldn't we be plotting $4\pi r^2 \psi ^2$ to get the probability density?

Comment: @AyumuKasugano. Please look up [`ArcTan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html) in the Documentation Center. You will find it has a two-argument form in Mathematica that resolves quadrant ambiguities.

Comment: Ah, but those aren't the correct conversions? $\theta$ isn't $\arctan{\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}$ and $\phi$ isn't $\arctan{\frac{x}{y}}$?

Comment: @AyumuKasugano. Then I don know what is going on. Remember, I didn't write the code.

Comment: @Ayumu, please look up `atan2` in Wikipedia. This is the correct way to do angle conversions instead of taking the arctangent of a ratio.