# Opacity or related issue with DensityPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, physics, opacity

I'm trying to make use of the function DensityPlot3D with the following specific example

```
DensityPlot3D[14.48 2.718^(2 Im[ArcTan[x,y]]) Abs[(Sqrt[x^2+y^2] SphericalBesselJ[1,7.72 Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]])/Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]]^2,{x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1},{z,-1,1},PlotLegends->Automatic,PlotRange->Automatic,PlotPoints->200]
```

from which I obtain (in the Mathematica notebook) a very opaque plot in gray as in this image:

[image]

> Is this normal? If not, what am I missing? How could I obtain a plot
>   like the one in the first answer of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32378/is-there-something-like-densityplot3d-to-visualize-atomic-orbitals) question?

I also tried copying and pasting exactly the same code in that first answer, and I get a plot with the same problem: "completely gray".

However, if a save the plot as .pdf (right click -> Save Graphic As...) the plot reappears "magically" much better:

[image]

I'm using Mathematica 12.0 Student Edition.

Comment: The `OpacityFunction` is assigning too much opacity I think. Try making that have a stronger cutoff. Admittedly, though, I don't see your base issue generally. One worth trying might be like: ``OpacityFunction -> (Which[# > .25, #/2, # > .1, .1, True, 0] &) ``

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks, I'll try other things. Your last command it didn't work either; I've tried even with a simpler function, namely `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]` and the plot is still awful.

Comment: this is an apparent bug in 12.0. I am using mmka on MacOSX and getting grey boxes even for the examples in mmka help for DensityPlot3D.

Comment: @bronxy Which example? The ones I tried work fine in 12.0 on MacOS.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Say even the very first one: DensityPlot3D[x y z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}] gets a grey cube. Latest version of MacOSX 10.14.6 on MacBook Pro 2018. If you know how to fix this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @bronxy Hmm.. I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ7Cz.jpg)

Comment: Please report this to support@wolfram.com, including the results of `SystemInformation[]` and details about your computer's OS version and hardware specs.

Comment: The plot domain, a cube of dimensions 20, is not consistent with the code domain, a plot of dimensions 2.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem (and a bunch of others) on  mmka 12.0.  Reseting the Mathematica subsystem, i.e., deleting all the mmka created folders in ~/Library, has solved this problem. Apparently something went wrong when upgrading from the previous version.