# Waterfall plot of a two dimensional function

Tags: plotting

I have the following plot, and I need to draw a waterfall plot of this. Does anyone know how I can make a waterfall plot in Mathematica?

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}]
```

I need something like the following picture:
[image]

Comment: Try `Show@Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Sin[x + y]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {x, 
   Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 10]}]` as a first attempt.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann, Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Or in a single `ParametricPlot3D`: `ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[
  Tooltip[{#, y, Sin[# + y]},
     StringForm["x = ``", #]] & /@
   Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 10]],
 {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the `Filling` option that needs to be there in 3D. I would do it as follows: separate $x_1$ and $x_2$ coordinates, plot in 2d, [add an extra dimension](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32378/is-there-something-like-densityplot3d-to-visualize-atomic-orbitals/32441#32441) and then put everything together with a `FaceGrids` option:

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[(First@
     Plot[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 2 π}, Filling -> Bottom, 
      FillingStyle -> 
       Directive[White, Opacity[1], Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}], 
      ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] /. {a_?AtomQ, b_?AtomQ} :> {a, y, 
      b}), {y, Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 10]}], Boxed -> False, 
 FaceGrids -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Black]]
```

[image]