# Unknown plotting issue

Tags: plotting, chemistry

I'm trying to model a surface based on the parameters listed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4y5gi8z5d06kr4srwrtkr/SIparametricv2-revisions.docx?dl=0&rlkey=9nw4b7w3lergzt129wva8cpsr), it's a 2p orbital isosurface using the equations *S10, S11, and S12*

My model is of a 2p surface, and should look like this:

[image: 2p orbital model from EQ]

But no matter how I tweak my code I end up with this:[image: 2p failed model]

```
model = ParametricPlot3D[
{Sin[x]*Cos[y]*(-2*ProductLog[0 - (0.003*Sqrt[6])/Abs[(Sqrt[3]*Sin[x]*Cos[y])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])]]), 
 Sin[x]*Sin[y]*(-2*ProductLog[0 - (0.003*Sqrt[6])/Abs[(Sqrt[3]*Sin[x]*Cos[y])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])]]), 
 Cos[x]*(-2*ProductLog[0 - (0.003*Sqrt[6])/Abs[(Sqrt[3]*Sin[x]*Cos[y])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])]])}, 
 {x, 0.040893729329, 3.10069892426}, 
 {y, ArcSin[0.0408823325378/Sin[x]], Pi -ArcSin[0.0408823325378/Sin[x]]}] 
    
 Export["model.stl", model]
```

[image: Code]

Comment: See my extended comment below. Also, please add to your question the specific function(s) from your linked paper that you want to plot in Mathematica.

Comment: Have you see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32378/is-there-something-like-densityplot3d-to-visualize-atomic-orbitals

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the Lambert function, this makes things only complicated, but plot the wave function or the probability directly. To be able to use `ContourPlot` you need to calculate the polar coordinates from the cartesian coordinates.

For an example I do not bother with the constants and set them all to 1 and I choose  l=1 and m=0. You are welcome to try other l and m. I then plot a contour surface of the probability. You will get some error message from the coordinate change calculation, because the polar coordinates are not defined at the origin. But this is only a single point and need not distract  us.

```
fun[x_, y_, z_] = 
  With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], th = ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], 
     ph = ArcTan[x, y]}, 
    Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, th, ph] (r Exp[-r/2] Cos[th])]]^2;
ContourPlot3D[fun[x, y, z] == .02, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -7, 7},
  BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually what I went with! I identified the Lambert function as my problem and got in touch with the paper's author, who directed me to another older paper using cartesian parametrics from which I generated the surfaces i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just an extended comment to perhaps help everyone understand what the OP has got so far...

I suggest addressing the `PlotRange` so you can see all of what you have, e.g.:

```
model = ParametricPlot3D[
  {
   Sin[x]*
    Cos[y]*(-2*
      ProductLog[
       0 - (0.003*Sqrt[6])/
         Abs[(Sqrt[3]*Sin[x]*Cos[y])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])]]), 
   Sin[x]*Sin[
     y]*(-2*ProductLog[
       0 - (0.003*Sqrt[6])/
         Abs[(Sqrt[3]*Sin[x]*Cos[y])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])]]), 
   Cos[x]*(-2*
      ProductLog[
       0 - (0.003*Sqrt[6])/
         Abs[(Sqrt[3]*Sin[x]*Cos[y])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])]])
   },
  {x, 0.040893729329, 3.10069892426},
  {y, ArcSin[0.0408823325378/Sin[x]], 
   Pi - ArcSin[0.0408823325378/Sin[x]]},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-10, 10}},
  ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]