# SphericalPlot3D generates flat surfaces

Tags: plotting, chemistry

I'm trying to plot a function r(theta, phi) but having some difficulty. It's also possible that I've misinterpreted [the paper I'm pulling these formula from](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4y5gi8z5d06kr4srwrtkr/SIparametricv2-revisions.docx?dl=0&rlkey=9nw4b7w3lergzt129wva8cpsr), but I think I'm most likely making some error in Mathematica.

This is the function I'm trying to plot, and the plot that the authors were able to generate:

[image: plot]
[image: A component of r]
[image: r(theta,phi)]

I'm using the code `SphericalPlot3D[-2*ProductLog[(0.003*Sqrt[6])/Abs[(Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}]`

and end up with this [image: Screenshot]

Comment: This appears to be the same as the question you asked here: [Unknown plotting issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239630/unknown-plotting-issue/239634#239634) .  Better to add to, expand, or clarify your original question than to start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Extended comment.

Just suggestions so that you can (maybe) see what you actually plot vs what you want to plot:

```
Plot3D[-2*
  ProductLog[(0.003*Sqrt[6])/
    Abs[(Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])]],
 {\[Theta], 0, Pi},
 {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All,
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

or...

```
SphericalPlot3D[-2*
  ProductLog[(0.003*Sqrt[6])/
    Abs[(Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]])/(2*Sqrt[Pi])]],
 {\[Theta], 0, Pi},
 {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi},
 PlotRange -> All,
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]