# Weird lines in my polyhedron

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, polyhedra

I'm seeing some weird artifacts on the corners of my Polyhedron:

```
PolyhedronData["RhombicHexecontahedron"]
```

[image]

Zooming in they look like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: I can reproduce it in [11.1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9e4SK.png)

Comment: It looks as if it is the edge behind the face that is poking through.

Comment: Don't have time to confirm but it looks like a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15735/5478

Comment: @Kuba at any rate [the solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29469/35000) proposed there works  for me in the case described here too.