# Extra Ticks in Chart Boxes?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, regions, charts

Is there a simple way to clean up the overextending ticks and highlight the line intersections?

```
BubbleChart3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 4}], PlotTheme -> "SolidGrid", 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementDataFunction["Cube", "Shape" -> "Square", 
   "Shading" -> "Fading", "TaperRatio" -> 1]]
```

[image]

I think I've seen this problem before but I can't find the post!

Comment: I think https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15735/69 is the one you were looking for.  (There may be others..)

Comment: @BrettChampion Ah yes that is it, is there any downside to setting that option to BSPTree globally?

Comment: The main downside to using the BSPTree is that it can be noticeably slower and/or memory intensive than other methods.