# Graphics3D rendering artifact (objects that should be obscured are partly visible through a triangle)

Tags: graphics3d, rendering, version-12

I have encountered a 3D rendering artifact that's about to drive me crazy. Here's a very minimal example:

```
triangle1 = {{0.8, 0, 0}, {0.997, 1, 0.5}, {0.8, 1, 0}};
triangle2 = {{1, 0, 0.5}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0.5}};
Graphics3D[Polygon[{triangle1, triangle2}]]
```

This produces the following image on my computer (ThinkPad X1 Carbon, Arch Linux, Mathematica 12.2.0.0):

[image: Two triangles]

At the upper right, parts of the edges of triangle1 that should be hidden behind triangle2 are in fact visible (when viewed from certain angles). Here's a zoom:

[image: Zoom on artifact]

I've played around with various `RenderingOptions`, which made no difference at all. The same artifact is also visible when exporting to PDF.

It's not limited to triangles only. For example, let's add a line segment:

```
triangle1 = {{0.8, 0, 0}, {0.997, 1, 0.5}, {0.8, 1, 0}};
triangle2 = {{1, 0, 0.5}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0.5}};
segment = {{1, 0.95, 0.5}, {0.95, 0.5, 0.4}};
Graphics3D[{Polygon[{triangle1, triangle2}], Line[segment]]
```

This segment should be completely obscured by triangle2 when viewed from the following angle, but as you can see, part of it bleeds through:

[image: Another zoom]

What's going on?!? Does this occur just on my system, or is it reproducible elsewhere? Are there any possible workarounds?

Comment: Seems to be fixed in version 13.0

Comment: @DanielHuber: OK, I'll try upgrading. But it would still be interesting to know if someone else experiences this in version 12, or if it's something peculiar to my system.

Comment: I can reproduce in 12.3.1 but not 11.3.0 or 13.0.0.  Must be a minor bug in version 12.

Comment: The bug is still on for example 13.0.0 on windows 10 if we zoom in the window！

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior can be turned off through the `Graphics3D` method option `"EdgeDepthOffset" -> False`. Some details are found [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html#462899223) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html#25806006).

Here's a comparison:

```
Graphics3D[Polygon[{triangle1, triangle2}]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[Polygon[{triangle1, triangle2}], Method -> {"EdgeDepthOffset" -> False}]
```

[image]

## Edit

Another option is to render all of your edges with thin tubes. This will prevent hidden edges that `"EdgeDepthOffset" -> False` can cause.

Here's some dummy data to compare all three methods:

```
ball = ImageMesh[RegionImage[Ball[], RasterSize -> 25]];
```

Default behavior, lines we shouldn't be seeing (red arrow):

```
Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
  MeshCoordinates[ball],
  MeshCells[ball, 2]
 ],
 Boxed -> False
]
```

[image]

`"EdgeDepthOffset" -> False` yields inconsistent line thickness (red arrow):

```
Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
  MeshCoordinates[ball],
  MeshCells[ball, 2]
 ],
 Boxed -> False,
 Method -> {"EdgeDepthOffset" -> False}
]
```

[image]

Thin tubes look good:

```
Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
  MeshCoordinates[ball],
  {
   {EdgeForm[], MeshCells[ball, 2]}, 
   {Black, Tube[MeshCells[ball, 1][[All, 1]], .0175]}
  }
 ],
 Boxed -> False
]
```

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much! Unfortunately, now some lines that I *want* to see become hidden or blurred, but I think I can solve that by adding an offset manually, so the situation is much improved. :-)

Comment: Right, see my edit.

Comment: Good suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative

```
Graphics3D[{...}, 
 BaseStyle -> RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTree"}]
```

It also works for [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265201/arrayplot3d-mesh-customization)

```
blank=ConstantArray[0,{10,10}];
block=ConstantArray[1,{10,10}];

ArrayPlot3D[{block,blank,blank,block,blank,blank,block,blank,blank,block},
  MeshStyle->Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2.5],Black],ImageSize->1200,
  BaseStyle->RenderingOptions->{"3DRenderingMethod"->"BSPTree"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works now.