# ArrayPlot3D mesh customization

Tags: plotting, mesh

I am trying to visualize a few 2D arrays in ArraryPlot3D. I think I have made it work, however, there is a minor detail on the mesh of the plot I want to improve.
For example, this is what the current 3d plot looks like:
[image: sample 3D plot]

However, if you look closely at the details of the edge, you will see there is a **tiny** tail, which I want to remove. I wonder if there is a easy way to achieve this? I notice that this effect is not prominent when the Mesh thickness is small.

tl;dr: I want to remove this tiny tail [image] in ArrayPlot3D when the mesh thickness is large.

Here I attach the sample code:

```
blank = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];

block = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}];

ArrayPlot3D[{block, blank, blank, block, blank, blank, block, blank, 
  blank, block}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2.5], Black], 
 ImageSize -> 1200]
```

Comment: I think this is the same issue: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262201/4346

Comment: @GregHurst seems like it... No idea how to fix it though

Comment: See my answer, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267288/2090

Comment: @chyanog can you also add your answer here, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an option, `BaseStyle->RenderingOptions->{"3DRenderingMethod"->"BSPTree"}`

```
blank=ConstantArray[0,{10,10}];
block=ConstantArray[1,{10,10}];

ArrayPlot3D[{block,blank,blank,block,blank,blank,block,blank,blank,block},
  MeshStyle->Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2.5],Black],ImageSize->1200,
  BaseStyle->RenderingOptions->{"3DRenderingMethod"->"BSPTree"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
blank = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];
block = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}];

ArrayPlot3D[{
  block, blank, blank, block, blank, blank,
  block, blank, blank, block},
 MeshStyle ->
  Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2.5], Black],
 ImageSize -> 1200,
 Method -> "ArrayMesh"]
```

[image]

Comment: Still have the same issue. I will try on my Windows machine to see if this is OS-related.

Comment: I used `"13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)"`

Comment: MacOS 12.3.1 and Win10 12.2.0 have the same effect. Upgrading Mathematica now to see if I can get it working.

Comment: Just tried "13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" still not working, let me try Windows version...

Comment: 13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022) also doesn't work...