# Weird ArraryPlot3D behavior

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, version-13

Just updated Mathematica to 13.0.1 on both Win and MacOS since trying to see if this [issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265201/arrayplot3d-mesh-customization) is solved,
and then I discovered more issues with the function:

[image]

Can anyone confirm this? If this can be fixed will be much better!

Here is the sample code:

```
blank = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];
block = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}];
rand1 = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}];
ArrayPlot3D[{block, blank, rand1}]
```

Comment: The mesh customization artifacts mentioned in the other post are present but see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP8sD.png) output for v12.2.0 Win7-x64.

Comment: @Syed I think this only applies to 13.0.1. I was plotting using 12.3.0 and no issue.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Works fine on 13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021), does not work on 13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022). You should report this problem to Wolfram Support.